# How to place comments on a full screen image?

Tags: java, android, imageview, comments

I'm working on a native android application in java with Android Studio and I want to add comments on full screen images like [this](https://i.s). This based upon a feature of ["Figma"](https://www.google.com/search?q=figma&oq=figma%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j35i39j0i512j69i60l4.4390j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) where you can place comments on prototypes.

I have already made a xml file that normally has an [Imageview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFYqn.png) in full screen. So I probably need to draw a circle on the exact coordinates of the view where I click. So how can I achieve this in java code?

[Figma example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSllh.jpg)

[Figma example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO5OZ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [draggable view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop) and when user clicks it display [dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) where they can enter a comment,
then save the position of the view and the comment to [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) or wherever you want so the user can retrieve it again whenever they need it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry if my explaination was hard to understand.

Comment: no it wasn't. hope my answer was helpful for you